# Angular,nodejs, mysql image upload

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular

i am trying to store an image in mysql database as blob using nodejs and angular the image gets inserted successfully but when i am not able to display the blob as image any ideas how to go through it
my code to insert:-

```
 const image = fs.readFileSync(file.path);
let base64data = image.toString('base64');
  db.query(qr, (err, result) => {
                if(err){
                    res.send({
                        err
                    })
                }else{
                    res.send({
                        message: "data sent successfully"
                    })
                }
            })
```

my code to display: -

```
.ts file: -
 display(){
    const reader = new FileReader();
    this.http.get('http://localhost:5000/image').subscribe((res:any)=>{
      console.log(res);
      this.readData = res.response[0];
  })
 
.html file:-
<td><img height="50" width="50"  src="data:image;base64,{{us.image.data}}"></td>
```

Comment: So wouldnt it be better to show us the code that you are using to fetch and display the image?

Comment: You have said your insert code is working... so it's not of much use to us. Show us the code that ISNT working. What are you doing to display the image?

Comment: Please use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70259211/edit) link under the question to add things to your question. Nobody can read code in a comment

Comment: @RiggsFolly done as you told any advise or change you need?

Comment: @DevWithZachary i provided the code you wanted anything else you need apart from the above mentioned code?